# How do specific tubeless valves compare to bodging it with a cut-off tube valve?

Tags: tubeless

How do specific tubeless valves compare to bodging it with a cut-off tube valve? Would the bodge work? Thanks

Comment: People have done the cut-off tube valve (search: ghetto tubeless). But given that a set of valves isn't all that much money, it doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: @Batman, the idea behind ghetto tubeless is not to use just the valve but the whole tube in place of rim tape. A cut off valve would need to be secured to the rim or it would just be blown out.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it done that way when the whole tube is split and used as a liner to make a tubeless system out of a non-tubeless wheelset.  As pointed out in the comments, if you already have a tubeless wheelset, the couple of bucks you save probably isn't worth the hassle you will experience trying to get the "bodged" valve to seal to the rim.  It might make more sense as an emergency measure if you have destroyed a tubeless valve.